# Node.js request aborted

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm using express and body-parser to send large amounts of data from one server to another, but I'm receiving this exception after some time:

```
{
    "message": "request  aborted",
    "code": "ECONNABORTED",
    "expected": 99010,
    "length": 99010,
    "received": 96872,
    "type": "request.aborted"
}
```

What could cause this? If you need more information, please let me know.

**UPDATE**
This is my configured limit:

```
application.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
application.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));
```

Comment: Is it a [limit](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#limit) issue?

Comment: Timeout? Due to a too large amount of data? Maybe you should consider streaming, instead of sending everything in one block

Comment: Also try executing you apps with the 'DEBUG=body-parser:*' env var, and check the body parser logs for internal warning/errors.

Comment: @Agustin, did you solved this issue?? I fetch the same error.

Comment: I've found this comment: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/207#issuecomment-521990161

Answer (score 5):

this is an exception thrown by raw body that is used by body-parser

from express-docs:

> **request aborted**
> This error will occur when the request is aborted by
> the client before reading the body has finished. The received property
> will be set to the number of bytes received before the request was
> aborted and the expected property is set to the number of expected
> bytes. The status property is set to 400 and type property is set to
> 'request.aborted'.

if you want to handle all request thrown from body parser for example

```
  'encoding.unsupported',
    'entity.parse.failed',
    'entity.verify.failed',
    'request.aborted',
    'request.size.invalid',
    'stream.encoding.set',
    'parameters.too.many',
    'charset.unsupported',
    'encoding.unsupported',
    'entity.too.large'
```

use this middleware

```
$ npm i express-body-parser-error-handler
```

and simply put it right after your body-parser initialization

```
const bodyParserErrorHandler = require('express-body-parser-error-handler')
...
...

application.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
application.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));
application.use(bodyParserErrorHandler());
...
```